# Adding values of a class Number to an ArrayList in a Hashmap of class Matrix

Tags: java

i have a class Number, which is suppose to represent a fraction number and implements an interface Calculation, and then class Matrix which is suppose to extend Class Number and represent a matrix, here is the code:

```
public interface Calculation {

    public int numberAddition();
    public int numberSubtraction();

}

public class Number implements Calculation {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Number(int n, int d) {
        numerator = n;
        denominator = d;
    }

    public Number() {
        this(0, 1);
    }

    public Number(int n) {
        numerator = n;
        denominator = 1;
    }
    public void setNumerator(int n) {
        numerator = n;
    }
    public void setDenominator(int d) {
        denominator = d;
    }

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }
    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String s = getNumerator() + "/" + getDenominator();
        return s;
    }

    public void setNumber(int n) {
        numerator = n;
        denominator = n;
    }

    public boolean equals(boolean b) {
        Object o1 = new Object();
        Object o2 = o1;
        if (o1 == o2) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public int numberAddition(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
    public int numberSubtraction(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }

}

public class Matrix extends Number {
    private HashMap < Integer, ArrayList < Number >> hm;
    private static int rows;
    private static int cols;

    public Matrix(int r, int c) {
        hm = new HashMap < Integer, ArrayList < Number >> ();
        rows = r;
        cols = c;
    }
    public void fillMatrix() {

    }
}
```

Now the questions:

1. When i make class `Number implement Calculation`, it says "Number must be abstract", when I make it abstract, it says "Matrix cant extend Number".
2. How can I fill the matrix using the `fillMatrix` method, how to fill the `ArrayList` and the `HashMap`?

Comment: you must override numberAddition and numberSubtraction methods in Number class.You overload these methods not override

Answer (score 1):

You have some design and [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) problems:

`Number` is a fraction; `Matrix` is *composed of* `Numbers`, it is not a `Number`. Then it should not `extends` it.

When a class implements an interface, it means it will fulfil some *capacity* or have some *behavior* described by the interface. In the code, the signature of the methods declared in the interface must match the one defined in the class that implements it.

In your case, the interface `Calculation` declare

```
public int numberAddition();
public int numberSubtraction();
```

without any parameters. Since you defined in the class `Number`

```
public int numberAddition(int x, int y) {...}
public int numberSubtraction(int x, int y) {...}
```

The compiler ask you to declare the class `abstract`. For him you don't fulfil the contract from `Calculation`.

A - may be - better interface would be

```
public interface Calculation {
   Number add(Number n);
   Number substract(Number n);
}
```

Then for `Matrix`, just remove the `extends Number`. In term of implementation the certainly simplest way is to have a 2-dimensional array either with plain java arrays or `List/ArrayList`

```
public class Matrix {
    private Number[][] hm;

    public Matrix(int r, int c)
    {
        hm = new Number[r][c];
    }

    // fill the matrix with Number n
    public void fillMatrix(Number n)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < hm.length; r++) {
           for (int c = 0; c < hm[r].length; c++) {
              hm[r][c] = n;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: in the implementation above, all matrix elements will reference the same instance of `Number`. It could be fine *if* `Number` is made immutable (i.e. with no setter). If you want to modify the matrix element in place, you should certainly initialise the matrix with a fresh instance for each element.

Answer (score 0):

If `Number` implements `Calculation`, it must declare the required methods--`numberAddition` and `numberSubtraction`. It may do this in two ways: either by declaring them with an implementation (body), or by declaring them `abstract`. If any of the methods of `Number` are declared `abstract` then the class must also be `abstract`.

I suspect that `Matrix` fails to compile because of the errors in `Number`. However, once those are fixed you should either compile fine (if `Number` is not `abstract`) or an error saying that `Matrix` needs to implement the `abstract` methods inherited from `Number`, or else declare them `abstract` as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you extend `Calculation` you need to provide an implementation `numberAddition()` and `numberSubtraction()` (without parameters). If you don't you will be force to make that class abstract but any non abstract class that extends `Number` will be forced to do it.
2. What do you want to do here? Fill your matrix ArrayList and HashMat with what? It will depend a lot on what you are trying to do.

Also, I don't get why your `Matrix` has to extend `Number`. Conceptually a Matrix **is not** a Number but an arrange of Numbers. So the inheritance rellationship is maybe not what you are looking for. Remember that inheritance can roughly be translated to "IS". A `Person` IS a `LivingThing`

Answer (score 0):

> 1) when i make class Number implement Calculation, it says number must
>   be abstract,

This is because  you dint provide a body to `public int numberAddition();` described in intrerface instead you make a new method `numberAddition(int x, int y)` (Note these both method are not same) nor you make `Number` as abstract which are the nessary condition for inplementing interface . So the error is thrown.

**Number is not abstract and does not override abstract method numberSubtraction() in Calculation**

> when I make it abstract, it says "Matrix cant extend Number".

Because again you dint provide implementation of interface methods in Matrix class as `Matrix` extend abstract class `Number` which implements interface.

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1.

Implement all the abstract methods in `Number`

```
    @Override
    public int numberAddition() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public int numberSubtraction() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

### Question 2.

An example of how to add to your `HashMap`

```
int key = 0;
ArrayList<Number> list = new ArrayList();

hm.put(key, list);
```

As another user has said, you have some issues with your class hierarchy. You will need another class that extends `Number` so that you can add this to your `Matix` `HashMap`.